# Body content overlapping navbar when scrolling

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to implement a navbar that stays fixed at the top on each page. However, the body portion of the pages keep on overlapping whenever it scrolls down. I'm not using bootstrap. I am trying to use AngularJS though, and trying to use partials with the index.html (insert by using ng-view). Here is my code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> 
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" > <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Web Portal</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/dashboard.css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/normalize.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/css/main.css">




</head>
<body>
  <!--[if lt IE 7]>
      <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
  <![endif]-->
<nav class='navbar'>
  <ul>
    <li id='floatleft'><a href="/">Dashboard</a></li>  
    <li id='floatleft'><a href="/grades">Grades</a></li>
    <li id='floatleft'><a href="/classes">Classes</a></li>
    <li id='floatright'><a href="/logout"><i class='material-icons'>power_settings_new</i></a></li>
    <li id='floatright'><a href="/profile"><i class='material-icons'>person</i></a></li>
    <li id='floatright'><a href="/msgs"><i class='material-icons'>mail</i></a></li>

    </ul>
</nav>

 <!--Here is where the other pages will be inserted-->   
 <div class="view-container">
     <div ng-view class="view-frame"></div>
 </div>

  <!-- In production use:
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script>
  -->
  <script src="../bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <!-- <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/x.x.x/angular.min.js"></script> -->
  <script src="../bower_components/html5-boilerplate/dist/js/vendor/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/version-directive.js"></script>
  <script src="components/version/interpolate-filter.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

dashboard.html:

```
<div>
  <span class='classmod'>
  <ul>
    <h1>Social Studies</h1>
    <li ng-repeat="announcement in announcements">{{announcement}}</li>
    <li>03/15: Second Midterm coming up</li>
    <li>03/10: <a href="hw5">Homework 5 due</a></li>
  </ul>
  </span>

  <span class='classmod'>
  <ul>
    <h1>Algebra II</h1>
    <li ng-repeat="announcement in announcements">{{announcement}}</li>
    <li>03/15: Second Midterm coming up</li>
    <li>03/10: <a href="hw5">Homework 5 due</a></li>
  </ul>
  </span>

  <span class='classmod'>
  <ul>
    <h1>History</h1>
    <li ng-repeat="announcement in announcements">{{announcement}}</li>
    <li>03/15: Second Midterm coming up</li>
    <li>03/10: <a href="hw5">Homework 5 due</a></li>
  </ul>
  </span>
</div>
```

dashboard.css:

```
body {
    /* prevents navbar from covering content at top of page */
    padding-top: 45px;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
}
.view-container {
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
}
.navbar {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: .9em;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin-top: 45px;
}
.navbar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: lightslategray;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
}
#floatleft a {
    float: left;
    padding: 13px 16px;
}
#floatright a {
    float: right;
    padding: 11px 10px;
}
.navbar a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:lightslategray;
    color: white;
}
.navbar a:hover {
    background-color: darkslategrey;
}
.active {

}
.classmod {
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.classmod li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

I tried to pad the body so that the body content would show up below the navbar and not overlap, and on the initial page load the body contents are below the navbar. Once you scroll up though, the body contents go straight over the navbar (you can see this if you resize the window until you can scroll up).

(Also, please ignore the ugly grey squares in the body content, I was trying to create little square modules for each class but haven't quite figured that part out yet.)

**Edit:** 
I have possibly fixed it by changing the css code like so:

```
body, html {
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    /* prevents body content from overflowing into navbar */
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.view-container {
    /* prevents body content from overflowing into navbar */
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Removed the padding, added the height: 100% and overflow:hidden to the html tag as well as the body tag. Not entirely sure why, but now the body isn't overflowing over the navbar...

Comment: Does the body have a display css attribute defined?  Is the nav bar positing declared?

Comment: If by display css you mean something like display:block;, then no, the body doesn't. Mainly because I thought it should be left open so that it could be more flexible with what is inserted in there? And I'm not sure what you mean by nav bar positing, I tried to make it fixed at the top?

Comment: it is a combination of these position: relative; display: block; and z-index; that you need to address.  Give the navbar a `z-index: 9999;`

Comment: Have you tested the solution across multiple browsers?